# What level of autonomy do regions within the Russian Federation have?

Tags: federalism, russian-federation

So, in the United States, of course, there is the 10th Amendment to the constitution, stating that powers not enumerated as adhering to the federal government are reserved either to the states or to the people.  In practice, this means there are several powers (education, welfare, and transportation come to mind) that really are the province of sovereign states.  Even if federal laws supercede state ones in many instances, states still have the right to appeal to the Supreme Court if their sovereignty has been impugned.

In the days of the USSR, individual republics had, I am at least led to believe, a similiar level of authority.  Boris Yeltsin, for example, rose to prominence precisely because he was able to secure Russia's rights over against the disintegrating USSR.

The question then is about the current Russian Federation.  To what extent are the constituent members sovereign entities? For example - could Chechnya or other autonomous Oblasts nullify a federal power?  Is there an entity to which the regions can appeal a federal power?  Or, are the constituent regions more akin to the [Dillion Rule](http://www.patobannon.com/frequently-asked-questions/what-is-the-dillon-rule) which states that counties are mere administrative divisions of the state?

In other words, what does federalism look like in the Russian Federation?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised at your mini-explanation of Dillion Rule. It seems to be (reading the link you provided) centered on not granting localities powers beyond those expressly stated, NOT on rationing of power between federal and local.

Comment: Yeah, its not a great link.  I'll see if I can find a better one.

Comment: "there are several powers (education, welfare, and transportation come to mind) that really are the province of sovereign states". Given the number of federal departments and dollars for these, that's a rather generous interpretation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but if you care about soveregnity, it's been conclusively [resolved](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) by Russian Constitutional Court in 2000 ([src](http://constitution.garant.ru/DOC_12019810.htm#sub_para_N_1)):

> Конституция Российской Федерации не допускает какого-либо иного носителя суверенитета и источника власти, помимо многонационального народа России, и, следовательно, не предполагает какого-либо иного государственного суверенитета, помимо суверенитета Российской Федерации. Суверенитет Российской Федерации, в силу Конституции Российской Федерации, исключает существование двух уровней суверенных властей, находящихся в единой системе государственной власти, которые обладали бы верховенством и независимостью, то есть не допускает суверенитета ни республик, ни иных субъектов Российской Федерации.

I won't bother with complete translation, TL;DR rough version is

> The only source of power in RF is multi-ethnic People(s) of Russia, and Constitution has no basis for any state sovereignty aside from that of Russian Federation; which totally excludes any '2-level' sovereign power"

The only appeals of federal power would be Constitutional Court.

---

As an aside - Russian Federation [only has ONE "Autonomous Oblast"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%28%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F) - [Jewish AO](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%90%D0%9E) (define irony - by now, due in part to extensive emigration by Jews, it has <1% population who are Jewish :)

All the other feeration subjects you are thinking of are "Republics", although some of them (not Chechnya) were AOs during USSR.

Comment: The last statement is grossly wrong: there are many subjects called krais and oblasts.

Comment: "The only appeals of federal power would be Constitutional Court." this statement is also wrong, when you are charged excess taxes, you appeal it to a local court.

Comment: @Anixx - if you can back that up, it's worth a separate answer, it's important information.

Comment: which statement exactly? The both are obvious.

Comment: @Anixx - about taxes. And you are welcome to cite a single modern "Avtonomnaya oblast" (not simply "oblast") other than EAO

Comment: you said that all other are republics - this is simply wrong.

Comment: So why isn't Russia considered to be a unitary state?

Comment: @JonathanReez - because it's a federation. A federation with low level of autonomy, but still a federation.

Answer (score 5):

```
For example - could Chechnya or other autonomous Oblasts nullify a federal power?
```

Neither it can, nor Soviet republics could, nor a US state can as I understand this question.

```
Is there an entity to which the regions can appeal a federal power?
```

Yes there is, they can appeal to a court.

You should note though that since 2004 the heads of the regions of the Russian Federation are not elected, but appointed by the president (this is outdated, the heads are elected again). As such it is unlikely any region would try to appeal the federal actions supported by the president. Yet the appeal to a court could be done by the elected regional parliament, the prosecutor's office, by individual parliament member or any other body whose interests are involved.

The court to which they would have to appeal depends on what act they want to appeal. In most cases of the presumably illegal actions of the ministries or federal agencies or in the case of contradictions inside the law they can appeal to a local court of the lowest level, which can then be escalated up to the supreme court in case of disagreements.

Comment: i doubt that any appeals in court from region on any subject ever take place. Russian Federation court system is not about justice, it is rather extension of penal system - it is the same as it was setup by Stalin in early 30's. Civil courts are weak and bribed easily. If region has any problems they have to go to Moscow and bribe some guys in Kermlin and/or Duma and try to make useful friends etc. Nothing to do with 'appeal court'. So called Constitution Court is pure circus and is dormant for quite some time.

Comment: @lowtech contrary to your opinion, I think such appeals happen on a regular basis, frequently. On the other hand, it depends on the definition of "appeal by a region", that is what regional bodies count.

Comment: could you give example of such appeal - Russian region appeals to Russian Federation in the court or elsewhere? I admit that I might miss something, would be glad to learn

Comment: ok, counted as example, i will review that and let you know. this is however very far from original question's subject on certain region autonomy level within Russian Federation. i don't think you will be able to find such examples.

Comment: @lowtech please tell me what examples are counted. Do you need an appeal by a region rather than by a city?

Comment: @lowtech this is the proceedings by a regional administration from Tambov oblast against Ministry of Defense: http://kad.arbitr.ru/Card/5ec5454b-c84e-45a6-b5c1-f9704ae5b56b

Comment: If you will find any court appeal from Tatarstan or Yakutia that would be counted.

Comment: @lowtech from what bodies of Tatarstan or Yakutia?

Comment: in the spirit of the question - from parliament of Tatarstan to some central government agency. Or from government of Yakutia.

Comment: @What do you mean by "government of Yakutia"? Does, say, department of property relations count? Or do you need the court appeal be signed by the head of the republic himself?

Comment: @lowtech Here, for example, Krasnoyarsk appeals against Ministry of emergency situations: https://www.my.arbitr.ru/Kad/Card/5551fbe2-88dd-4f33-9761-1f130eb9d574 Krasnoyarsk is the center of Krasnoyarsk krai, a subject to the federation.

Comment: "since 2004 the heads of the regions of the Russian Federation are not elected, but appointed by the president" - this information is outdated. Since 01.06.2012 the governors are elected. In 2013 there were mayor elections in Moscow.

Answer (score 3):

Russia is very different from western countries in a sense that corruption of public officials is playing major role in country governance. essentially central power prescribes on how much each governor can steal from federal budget cut and governors are doing the same down the power chain. kickbacks are norm, it was finally admitted by some sochi olympics contractors. everything else (like degree of autonomy for individual region) doesn't matter. there is additional factor in North Caucus (Chechnya, Dagestan). Because of their natural separatism that regions receive bigger cuts from federal budget.

To be a bit more specific on how it works:

Federal powers in Moscow know everything about kickbacks in region thanks for FSB spying abilities.
If someone violates rules about 'level of autonomy' or just stealing too much
then the governor is replaced.

75% GDP of Russia is related to fuel exports. Since Putin came to power federal revenue based on taxes and fees related to that increased from 40% in 2000, to 84% in 2005 to 98% in 2013 (from http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D4%E5%E4%E5%F0%E0%EB%FC%ED%FB%E9_%E1%FE%E4%E6%E5%F2_%D0%EE%F1%F1%E8%E8). I.e. right now all money go to Moscow.

Almost all regions are dependent on redistribution of this big oil-natgas revenue pie. There are negotiations between Moscow and regions on this subject and then region get it's piece. Region has it's own decision power where the money goes. Here where regional kickbacks started:

http://www.kompromatural.ru/basarginu_vekselbergu_prorochat_obschee_ugolovnoe_delo
-- in Perm, Basargin and Vekselberg
http://www.compromat.ru/page_29655.htm -- in Pskov region Turchak

But sometimes governor get arrested:

http://www.compromat.ru/page_34389.htm -- Novosibirsk governor arrested, kickback schema with Oleg Deripaska participation.

Here mentioned about kickbacks from region to Kremlin (paragraph 9): https://wikileaks.org/cable/2010/02/10MOSCOW317.html, whole document is about Moscow mayor corruption empire.

Comment: Can you prove, what you say: "central power prescribes how much each governor can steal from federal budget"?

Comment: @user4035 I added some urls to materials in russian websites to illustrate the picture. This is mostly yellow press articles. wikileaks may have more materials on this subject.

Comment: This does not answer the question IMHO.